# add jquery bunch of inline codes in prestashop module file not working

Tags: php, jquery, module, prestashop

I am just newbie to the [prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com/). Currently I am creating a small module in prestashop. I want to add some jQuery inline codes to the modulename.php file. But its not working there. Can someone kindly tell me how to use jQuery codes to the prestashop module files. Any help and suggestions will be really apprecaible. Thanks

My sample code goes like this

```
public function getContent() {
      $this->_html = '<h2>'.$this->displayName.'</h2>';

    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitUpdate')) {
      Db::getInstance()->Execute('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'tablename` SET `function_name`="'.$body_option.'",`height`="'.$height.'",`width`="'.$width.'"');

      $this->_displayForm();
      return $this->_html;
    }
  }



  private function _displayForm() {
    $this->_html .=  '
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../modules/modulename/css/store_styles.css" />
      <script src="../modules/modulename/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';

      $this->_html .= '<input type="file" name="file" id="file"  multiple/>';

    $this->_html .= '
      <form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" id="test">';

    $this->_html .= '<div class="clear"></div></div>
      <label>'.$this->l('Upload Image').' </label>
      <div class="margin-form">';
      $this->_html .= '<input type="file" name="file" id="file"  multiple/>';
      $this->_html .= '</div>';

        $this->_html .= '
        <div class="margin-form clear"><input type="submit" name="submitUpdate" value="'.$this->l('Save').'" class="button" /></div>
        </form>      
  }
```

So as per my requirment when I will click on checkbox then this piece of code should work.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('input[name="file"]').change(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).val() == 'yes'){
      jQuery('input[type="file"]').prop('multiple', true);
    }else{
        jQuery('input[type="file"]').prop('multiple', false);
    }
  });
</script>
```

**Remember** That this form is for admin and I want the piece of jQuery codes in the backend.

Comment: What does your Firebug says about loaded Javascript? What version of Prestashop are you using? Adding CSS and JS files is more comfortable using (in PS 1.5.x) `$this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path) . 'css/module.css');` syntax. Also HTML can be inserted into module template file.

Comment: I am using PrestaShop™ 1.5.4.1 version. Firebug is not showing any error and also the js codes are working.

Comment: If so, then I would try some JS `console.log()` debugging. To see what is really happening, I don't see any obvious mistake in your code. Also isn't `multiple` attribute supported only in HTML5? Prestashop 1.5.x is running on XHTML 1.1. Maybe this is the cause of your problem. Check [www.wufoo.com](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/) for `multiple` browser support.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the local ones, try something like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I understood that jquery doesn't work, because it's not loaded from "../modules/modulename/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js", that's why I offered an alternative solution. But maybe I misunderstood the problem.